# adding pan gesture recognizer in specific area

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I would like to add this pan recognizer not for whole screen it should be in specific area.

```
- (void)panDetected:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panRecognizer
{
    CGPoint translation = [panRecognizer translationInView:self.documentImageView];
    CGPoint imageViewPosition = self.documentImageView.center;
    imageViewPosition.x += translation.x;
    imageViewPosition.y += translation.y;

    self.documentImageView.center = imageViewPosition;
    [panRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
}
```

Can this pan recognizer be in this self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame at the top ?

```
- (void)setExtractedImageForTableView:(UIImage *)extractedImage 
  {   
        self.documentImageView.image = nil;
        self.documentImageView = nil;
        self.documentImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:extractedImage];

        self.documentImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panDetected:)];
        [self.documentImageView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

        self.documentImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        if (!CGSizeEqualToSize(extractedImage.size, CGSizeZero)) {

         self.documentImageView.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.view.frame), CGRectGetMinY(self.tableView.frame), CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), (extractedImage.size.height/extractedImage.size.width) * CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame));
         self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.documentImageView;

         [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
         CGRect frame = self.documentImageView.frame;
         frame.size.height = self.documentImageView.frame.size.height + 100;
         self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
         self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame = frame;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add UIView in UITableView header View and then add gesture in that view .

Comment: cant i add as subview of tableView.tableHeaderView.frame ?

Comment: if you have storyboard then you can drag UIView in TableView other wise you can add uiview as subview in tableview.tableHeaderView

Comment: okay after that how can i add gestureRecognizer of that view's subview? im harcoding btw not creating from storyboard.

Comment: suppose this is your subview --- panView
panView.userInteractionEnabled = Yes;
[panView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

Comment: okay when i zoom .. its still covering whole screen :/ @abhishek

Comment: actually am i not doing the same in my setExtractedImageForTableView method?